# Does global choice allow to extend the natural well-order on On to a well-order of the whole universe

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Suppose that T is a set theory with global choice (for example ZF+ global choice).
Question: Does T prove the existence of a well-order on the whole universe V whose restriction to the class On of ordinals is the natural well-order on ON ?
Gérard Lang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use global choice to choose, for each ordinal $\alpha$, a well-ordering $<_\alpha$ of the sets of rank $\alpha$ in the cumulative hierarchy.  Then well-order all the sets by putting $x$ before $y$ if either $x$ has lower rank than $y$ or they have the same rank $\alpha$ and $x<_\alpha y$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this question has been migrated from MathOverflow to MathOverflow. I wasn't previously aware that such vacuous migrations were possible.

Comment: I think it was migrated from meta?